# identify which clients get disconnected using java NIO

Tags: java, android, nio

I have created a sample [of Java NIO](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) and created a server where different clients get connected.

Now the issue is i want to track how many clients are connected over socket.
for example ,

if A , B , C and D are connected to Server S1 then if B and C got disconnected S1 will come to know that these clients got disconnected through Java NIO apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a client disconnects cleanly, your `SocketChannel` to that client will become readable and a `read()` will return -1.

If the connection is aborted, the only way you can detect it is by writing and getting a subsequent `IOException`.